# Algebraic geometry: well definedness of the the vanishing locus of the denominator of rational functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the following proof from Steve Dale's introduction to algebraic geometry:

[image]

[image]

So I am a bit confused about the highlighted part, because rational functions are by definition equivalence classes and we have only chosen one amongst many possible representatives. So if we choose a different $g$ then we might have to choose a different $p$. How do we know there actually exist a $p$ such that even if we cycle through all the possible representatives of $g$, the point $p$ does not belong to the vanishing locus of $g$?

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there might be many different $g$'s that work, and the choice of $p$ depends on the choice of $g$. However, for each $g$ there is a $p$.

First note that that $Z(g)$ is a proper closed subset of $X$: There are points in $X$ where $g$ does not vanish. Second we need that the Zariski open set $U$ is dense. This is true for any Zariski open in a variety. Combining the two facts yields $U \not\subset Z(g)$, because otherwise we would have $X = \overline U \subset Z(g) \subsetneq X$, which is absurd. So there exists a point $p \in U \setminus Z(g)$.